# Customise JSON-LD attributes in Product schema

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am using default behaviour of the JSON-LD spartacus implementation.
I am getting below error and warning in the debugger
[image]

how can I remove those are not required and repalce values for Name with Description , which is by default

Comment: See the Spartacus code how does this work: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/tree/develop/projects/storefrontlib/src/cms-structure/seo/structured-data/builders/product
I'd check is API returning required data and if yes, override the default product json-ld builder so it construct required json-ld structure (in our case we had to add brand and offer builders and modify the base product one).

Comment: thanks @MirosławGrochowski,  overriding JsonLdBaseProductBuilder  class, soluton worked for me